# What should implementations for #getType() and #getStreamTypes() in content provider look like when sharing all types of files

Tags: android, mime-types, android-contentprovider

I have a file system management app, and I am sharing all types of files with external 3rd party applications using a content provider.

My question is:
What should implementations for #getType() and #getStreamTypes() in content provider look like?

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

[See docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) for ContentProvider

```
getType (Uri uri)
```

Implement this to handle requests for the MIME type of the data at the given URI. The returned MIME type should start with vnd.android.cursor.item for a single record, or vnd.android.cursor.dir/ for multiple items.

```
getStreamTypes (Uri uri, String mimeTypeFilter)
```

Called by a client to determine the types of data streams that this content provider supports for the given URI. The default implementation returns null, meaning no types. If your content provider stores data of a particular type, return that MIME type if it matches the given mimeTypeFilter. If it can perform type conversions, return an array of all supported MIME types that match mimeTypeFilter.

Comment: Yes I have read docs on the methods, but my problem is that they require that I keep every MIME type that I support in a memory, so when the methods are called I can supply required MIME type according to the uri parameter.

What if I don't know what types I will support because in file system app you can have any type of a file.